# How to show tag names with Ansible Dynamic Inventory for AWS?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

How can I make ansible-inventory output show tag:Name (and instance-id if possible) when running ansible-inventory but use the instance-id for ansible_host when I am running a playbook since I am using SSM as connection?

inventory_aws_ec2.py:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-1
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: Team
  - key: tags.Team
filters:
  instance-state-name: running
hostnames:
  - instance-id
compose:
  ansible_host: instance-id
```

ansible-inventory:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory_aws_ec2.yml --graph
@all:
|--@aws_ec2:
| |--i-01db65678937d3ff8
| |--i-31a878777499b62c0
|--@Team_Devops:
| |--i-01vf87653998d3ff8
| |--i-31a878777499b62c0
|--@ungrouped:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name` tag only:

```
hostnames:
  - 'tag:Name'
compose:
  ansible_host: instance_id
```

`Name_id` format:

```
hostnames:
  - name: 'instance-id'                                                         
    separator: '_'                                                              
    prefix: 'tag:Name' 
compose:
  ansible_host: instance_id
```